# issue of the recognize people by their clothes color with not severe illumination environments

Tags: image-processing, data-extraction, hsv, color-tracking

I am interested in the human following using a real robot.
I'd like to use the color of clothes as a key feature to identify the target person in front of the robot to follow him/ her but I am suffering due to it is a weak feature with a very simple illumination changing. So, I  need to alter this algorithm to another or update values (RGB) online in real-time but I don't have enough experience with image processing.

this is my full code for color detection:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from imutils.video import FPS
# capturing video through webcam
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

width = cap.get(3)  # float
height = cap.get(4)  # float
print width, height
time.sleep(2.0)
fps = FPS().start()
while (1):
    _, img = cap.read()

    if _ is True:
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    else:
        continue
    # blue color

    blue_lower = np.array([99, 115, 150], np.uint8)
    blue_upper = np.array([110, 255, 255], np.uint8)
    blue = cv2.inRange(hsv, blue_lower, blue_upper)
    kernal = np.ones((5, 5), "uint8")
    blue = cv2.dilate(blue, kernal)
    res_blue = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=blue)

            # Tracking blue
    (_, contours, hierarchy) = cv2.findContours(blue, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for pic, contour in enumerate(contours):
        area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        if (area > 300):
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
            cv2.putText(img, "Blue Colour", (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (255, 0, 0))
    cv2.imshow("Color Tracking", img)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
    fps.update()

    # stop the timer and display FPS information
    fps.stop()
#    print("[INFO] elapsed time: {:.2f}".format(fps.elapsed()))
#    print("[INFO] approx. FPS: {:.2f}".format(fps.fps()))
```

these are the outputs:

1- recognize a person by his clothes color

[image: recognize a person by his clothes color]

2- it is lost, the illumination changing is a very simple not severe

[image: it is lost]

Any ideas or suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does look like you need to use a bit more advanced color similarity function to handle complex cases. [Delta E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference) will be the right starting point.

Proper threshold or several colors with associated thresholds will help to achieve pretty accurate results:

[image]

See the list of colours on the right side

[image]

[Complete example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-vOm5rgMhI).

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, it seems that be good for my purpose, do you know the paper of this video or code??

Comment: Well, I did the implementation (which is multi color image segmentation based on delta E) and processed the video. You can find more examples here: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCLsVHuYpywKFNAHKFfImIVg/videos

As for the paper, a similar approach described here: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5295/31b8de8ef9578e32bb37008598d263d2dbec.pdf

Comment: can I implement it in python? if yes. please help me, I search more after reading your answer here but I can't get it.

Comment: @Algabri, basically, you need to extend the range of colors. You have blue_lower and blue_upper (for example https://medium.com/@ckyrkou/color-thresholding-in-opencv-91049607b06d) . Instead of doing that you can specify blue as a base color and check every single pixel using delta_E (https://python-colormath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/delta_e.html) with a proper threshold to get better similarity.