# detecting wheel color and print it out in the console

Tags: image-processing, colors, detection, opencv, python

I have images of wheels and I need to print out the color of the wheel from the image.The colors to be detected are Black, Gray, Silver, White, Bronze, Blue, Red and Green.

I started by defining color boundaries and detecting color ranges and displaying the values on the console. But now, I'm looking to print out the wheel color only, and I can not take the highest pixel count value, because the highest value will be for image background.

The wheels are always large and are located in the center. They are always wheels, and the background is always solid. It can't be patterned or striped or random, and the color is either white or gray only.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys

image = cv2.imread('/home/devop/Pictures/11.jpg')


color_boundaries = {
    "Red":    ([0,   0,   255], [127, 0,   255]),
    "Green": ([0 , 255 , 0], [0 , 255 , 0]),
    "Blue":   ([255, 38,  0],   [255, 38,  0]),
    "White": ([255 , 255 , 255],[255 , 255 , 255]),
    "Black": ([0 , 0 , 0],[0 , 0 , 0]),
    "Bronze": ([205,   127, 50], [205,   127, 50]),
    "Gray":   ([160, 160, 160], [160, 160, 160]),
    "Silver": ([192 , 192 , 192],[192 , 192 , 192])

}

for color_name, (lower, upper) in color_boundaries.items():
    # create NumPy arrays from the boundaries
    lower = np.array(lower, dtype = np.uint8)
    upper = np.array(upper, dtype = np.uint8)

    # find the colors within the specified boundaries and apply the mask
    mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
    output = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = mask)

    if mask.any():
        print(f"{color_name}: {mask.sum()}")
```

What I got after executing the program :

```
White: 50822520
Black: 1020
Gray: 8925
Silver: 11985
```

Sample Image :

[image]

Comment: Is the background always white?

Comment: @MarkSetchell the background usually white, gray, and silver.

Comment: You need to be more specific about the constraints otherwise people will either not bother helping or they will spend an age making a solution that doesn't work because they assumed something that is not correct because it is not properly explained. Are the wheels aways large and central in the image? Are they always wheels? Could the background be patterned or striped or random? How well separated is the silver wheel from the silver background, or the black wheel from the black background?

Comment: @MarkSetchell thank you for your support, the wheels always large and central in the image, and they are always wheels, the background couldn't be patterned or striped or random, we can say the background either white or gray only, now i will update my question with these points .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a robust solution I'd suggest to avoid verifying all pixels and concentrate on the approach when you use background color (which is supposed to be solid) to isolate the area of the interest. Here is the concept:

1. use some insights to identify the the background
2. isolate the wheel area
3. do the required analyzis

Sounds simple and actually it is:

1. unless wheels are designed for a bumpy ride you can use any corner of the image to identify the background
2. use color thresholding to get everything but the background
3. (optional step) you might want to adjust threshold in a way secondary parts are excluded
4. verify colors within identified area (target color will dominate), use [delta E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference) to find the closest one (also [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58498862/issue-of-the-recognize-people-by-their-clothes-color-with-not-severe-illuminatio/58520284#58520284))

Here is a quick PoC:

**1. Get the background**

[image]

**2. Color-based segmentation**

[image]

**3. Optional tuning**

[image]

Step 4 seems to be pretty straightforward.