# Is there any method that can segment a bead on this image without assigning a bounding box?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-segmentation, contour

I am interested in segmenting this bead without involving a bounding box. I got outstanding results when I used level sets, active contour, snakes, and others.
The poor results were obtained when I used K-means clustering, thresholding with morphological operations, among others. Could anyone recommend me a method that can segment a bead without assigning a region of interest bounding box?

[image]

Comment: AI/Deep learning can do that. See https://www.remove.bg, for example. Unfortunately, that is not readily available in OpenCV..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do that, but you need to have a clear distinctive feature defined anyway. For example, I've just tried color-based segmentation (there is a clear difference in color):

[image]

So if the scene can be improved a bit to make the color of the object of interest distinctive -- there will be no problem getting accurate results. It is likely no improvements are possible taking into account the process you are working with, so instead you can use any suitable approach to build a training set and train a model.

I'd suggest to follow that way (which is the most common), but there is another option: depth or 3D camera (Intel RealSense for example). The scene you have from the depth perspective is quite straightforward, so there should be no problem segmenting the actual object.

BTW, here is vectorised and a bit beautified form:

[image]

I'm showing that to highlight another "life-hack": sometimes it is hard to deal with bitmaps, so vectorised form will be definitely a better choice.

Comment: just curious, what software is shown in your picture?

Comment: @Guang, segmentation results are produced by a custom tool, second screenshot is inkscape.org

Comment: I was wondering if the segmentation procedures involved coding. If possible can you explain more about color segmentation because I tried with python the results were not good? Thanks

Comment: @KimwagaMakono, sorry, no coding. Steps are: improve contrast, define a target color(s), do the segmentation. Your results might not be good because of color matching function. It should be deltaE (check the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61688848/1435741)

Comment: Thank you for your concern, I will check on the suggestions!