# How to determine the external contour of the black object detected through the saturation values from the HSV color space

Tags: python, opencv, binary, image-segmentation, contour

I have an image obtained from welding similar to this [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68734761/is-there-any-method-that-can-segment-a-bead-on-this-image-without-assigning-a-bo). I converted the input image from BGR2GRAY, removing the red channel, and then extracting the saturation value using opencv as shown in the snippet below:

```
image = cv2.imread('capture.png')
image.shape
hsvImage = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
cv2.imshow('saturation',hsvImage[:, :, 1])
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

After extracting the saturation values, the resulting image is as follows

[image: saturation]

I tried to use `connected-componets, thresholding, clustering etc` but the results are not promising because some white points remain. Any advice to handle this

Comment: Perhaps do median filtering. Then invert so the object is white on dark background. Then do some morphology open and close to remove small dark areas and fill in white gaps. Then get the external contours and get the largest contour.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This was the first procedure to attempt, the results were not as clear as the one obtained by using Morphological geodesic active contour. The drawback of this algorithm is that 'It requires initialization'. I am trying to check for an algorithm that can work on real-time applications without initializations.

Comment: I suspect you will then need AI/Deep Learning with training.

Comment: I think so but I have a limited number of images to start with, otherwise I would have jumped into to deep learning

Comment: Did you try applying kmeans processing with n=3? Then use morphology to clean up some. The get the largest contour.

Comment: FYI http://remove.bg does a nice job on your image. Can you use online tools or get a license for it.

Comment: I tried k-means too it was last year, I used remove.bg to create the ground-truth it was awesome. Thank you for your recommendations about that.